# Multivariable calculus finding steepest slope with no given coordinates

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, gradient-descent

A hill can be described by $h(x,y) = 300e^{-(x^2+y^2)}$, where $x$ and $y$ are horizontal distances (in km) measured in the directions East and North, respectively, and $h$ is the height (in m) of the ground above the sea level.

A rail way runs SW to NE and follows the straight line $x-y=2$. What is the steepest slope that the trains will have to climb?

**My working**

First I found the partial derivatives
$$\frac{\partial h}{\partial x} = -600000xe^{-(x^2+y^2)}$$
and
$$\frac{\partial y}{\partial x} = -600000ye^{-(x^2+y^2)}$$
and then I know that $y=x-2$ is a straight line passing through (0,-2), therefore its directional vector is just gonna be $(\vec{i} + \vec{j})$, and naturally its unit vector would be $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(\vec{i} + \vec{j})$
Now I understand that if I take the dot product of the $\nabla$ and unit vector $\hat{\vec{r}}$, that would give me the steepest ascent. However, I'm not sure how I would go about finding the steepest slope since I wasn't given any coordinates?

Comment: As a first comment, your partial derivatives seems to be a factor $10^3$ too large.

Comment: Your partials are wrong by a factor of about 1000. and you've written y where you meant h in the second equation. To answer your question: $r \cdot \nabla$ gives the slope in the direction $r$. The only problem you have to deal with is units: in what units is the slope supposed to be expressed? meters per kilometer? meters per meter? That's perhaps the trickiest bit here.

Comment: But $h$ is in m and $x$ and $y$ are in km?

Answer (score 2):

Steepest slope occurs at point of inflection, at zero curvature point in any direction as it is polar symmetric. I let $y=0$ and set $h=y$ hoping it would not confuse, just I wished you to recognize the standard Gaussian Bell distribution.

$$ \frac{dy}{dx} = - xy/ \sigma^2 \tag1 $$

which is what gives the distribution profile  basically. Now set $y^{\prime \prime} $ to zero ( as it is for any product,and simplify

$$ \frac{dy}{dx} = -\frac{y}{x} \tag2 $$

Eliminate $y$ in equated RHS of (1) and (2) to obtain point of inflection of maximum slope.

$$ x=\pm \sigma \tag3 $$

Finally integrate for shape of Bell

$$ y= y_0 \,e^{ {-x^2}/{2 \sigma^2}  } \tag4$$

Comment: Perhaps you should elaborate or change this to a comment.

Comment: Thanks. I elaborated it a bit..

Answer (score 2):

First, as two commenters have indicated, your leading coefficients are way too large.  But once you've fixed that, you're almost there.  Take the dot product you mention to get

$\displaystyle
\frac{dh}{dl} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}( \partial_x h + \partial_y h)$

This is a function of both $x$ and $y$, but you know the relationship between $x$ and $y$: $x-y=2$.  So substitute for either $x$ or $y$ in $dh/dl$ to get a function in one variable, $x$ say.  Fortunately in this example, you don't have to worry about any scaling between $\partial_x$ and $\partial_y$.  (Do you understand why?)  Now take the derivative of *that* function with respect to whichever independent variable you chose and find where *that* derivative is zero and there is your maximum slope.  If you need the actual value of that slope, you will have to account for the difference in scaling between $\partial_x$ and $d/dl$.

Comment: Why do I not have to worry about scaling between $\partial_x$ and $\partial_y$?

Comment: Also why does your method work? Why does it work when u set a function in one variable, and make its derivative equals to zero?

Comment: To your first question, bec. of given relationship between $x$ and $y$, $\Delta x$ = $\Delta y$.  If eqn had been, for exmpl, $x-2y=2$, then $\partial_x \neq \partial_y$.  To your second question, you are *simply given the relationship* between $x$ and $y$.  If you know $x$, you automatically know $y$ and vice versa.  So if you have an expression that involves both, like $dh/dl$, then you can just substitute one of them.  Finally, you have the expression for the slope, that is, $dh/dl$.  The maximum of this function, as with any function at all, will be the place where its derivative is zero.